# Ionic Push: Error: INVALID_SENDER - IONIC 2

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, firebase, push-notification, cordova-plugin

Fala galera!

Estou desenvolvendo um app no qual tenho que usar push notification. 
Segui todo o tutorial guid do IONIC neste [link](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/), mais de uma vez, e não obtive êxito.

Também segui [este](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUjQ3G17T80) tutorial que realiza as notificações através do próprio Firebase, mas também não obtive sucesso.

No primeiro exemplo o IONIC nem finaliza o push, fica só encaminhando.
No segundo exemplo o Firebase finaliza a notificação, mas não recebo no app.

Descobri o erro utilizando o inspec devices do google chrome (chrome://inspect/#devices) e aparece a seguinte mensagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Verifiquei repetidas vezes o meu Sender_id e está correto. Já pesquisei diversas vezes em vários links do google e não obtive resposta que solucionasse meu problema.

Se serve de alguma coisa, segue parto do meu package.json relativos ao ionic, cordova e phonegap.

```
    "@ionic-native/browser-tab": "4.0.1",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.0.1",
"@ionic-native/push": "4.0.1",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.0.1",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.0.1",
"@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.12.0",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
"cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
"cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-browsertab": "^0.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.1",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
"ionic-angular": "3.0.0",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"phonegap-plugin-push": "^1.10.5",
```

Enfim, não sei mais o que fazer. Aguardo qualquer ajuda. Desde já grato!

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o problema ao rodar o comando adb logcat.

Quando eu configurei a primeira vez o meu app, também foi a primeira vez que estava realizando configuração de um push notification e acabei colocando o valor errado no sender_id. Contudo, depois eu alterei para o correto, mas não estava sendo replicado em todos os arquivos. Ficou faltando alterar no main.js, map.js, entre outros.

No log do adb vi que a variável sender_id estava com o valor errado, copiei o valor e pesquisei por todas as referências desse valor (ctrl + shift + f, no VS Code) e alterei todas, assim solucionando o problema.

O estranho é que eu removi a plataforma e adicionei de novo, sendo assim era pra ter alterado os valores.

Enfim, espero ajudar mais pessoas, caso se depare com esse erro.